# Nested span tag needs to enforce a horizontal scroll bar in outer div tag

Tags: html, css

I have a table created using div tags, nested div tags and nested span tags (no actual table element). When a inner span tag's contents get too wide, the horizontal scroll bar will not show up for the outer div tag. E.g.

```
<div>Some text 
  <span> Here is the suuuuuuuper wide text</span>
</div>
```

Does anyone know how to get the div tag to display the horizontal scroll bar when the inner span tag content's get too wide?

Edit: using overflow:scroll makes the scroll bar always displayed and I only want the scroll bar displayed when the inner span tag content is too wide.

Answer (score 0):

Just have the text scroll when it gets too long by assigning an overflow to the div css.

```
div { overflow: scroll;}
```

Comment: Thank you, this works, but I only want the scroll bar to show up when needed and not always be there

Comment: div { overflow: auto;}

Comment: I tried this as well, but for some reason when the inner span tag gets too wide, the outer div never shows the horizontal bar.

Is it possible that some other class/style is override overflow:auto? 

I would assume overflow:auto on the div tag would allow for the scroll bar to show anytime the inner span tags get too wide. This is default behavior, correct?

Comment: Could you provide a fiddle so I can get a better idea of the issue.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you'd just need a width on your div, and `white-space: no-wrap;` on the span to keep it from flowing down onto the next line. If you want a single line, also add no-wrap to the div itself.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ZmLbs/

```
<div>Some text 
  <span> Here is the suuuuuuuper wide text</span>
</div>

<div>Some text 
  <span> Here is shorter text</span>
</div>

<div class="single-line">Some text 
  <span> Here is single-line text</span>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div {
    width: 150px;
    border: 1px solid red;
    overflow-y: auto;
}
span {
    white-space:nowrap;
}
.single-line {
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```